# Appending to dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set a dynamically created divs with the same class name. Now I want to append a entirely new div to all of the above mentioned divs.

Say the class name is extra-upper-block

At the end of my page I have this code

```
<script>
    //function call to load dynamic content
</script>
<script>
    $('.extra-upper-block').append('<div>New Div</div>');
</script>
```

This throws an error in chrome's console

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

But when this code is executed in chrome's console after the page is loaded, it works! 
Why doesn't it work even when I load the dynamic content before executing the append command. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery class selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.extra-upper-block').append('<div>New Div</div>');
});
```

Wrap your code in `$(document).ready()` for jQuery to get the elements available, and include jQuery file reference.

*Note* : `.append()` method is a part of jQuery.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6pWAZ/)

Comment: enclosing inside $(document).ready() and using jquery selectors fixed the problem. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object, you can't use it like jQuery, you need to access the individual element in a loop. Also, use `appendChild` on DOM elements, because they don't have an `append` method (like jQuery does).

Also, you are trying to append a string `<div>New div</div>`, you can't directly do that with a DOM element, so instead you can create the div element like so:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WBaVy/)**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('extra-upper-block');

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('New div'));
    elements[i].appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Note: `querySelectorAll` has better cross browser support than this. If you have jQuery included you can simply do:

```
$('extra-upper-block').append('<div>New Div</div>');
```

As you can see, with jQuery you can append a string directly.

Comment: enclosing inside $(document).ready() and using jquery selectors fixed the problem. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

try writing

```
document.getElementsByClassName('extra-upper-block')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is a function in jQuery, try this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
      $('.extra-upper-block').append('<div>New Div</div>');
});  
</script>
```